# Minecraft: Pistons to stop water flow

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make it so that I can push pistons upwards to stop water.

[image: confused]

So what I am trying to do is push up the piston to stop the water that is one block above and behind it. I dont know too much about redstone configurations so i thought i would ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can power a block adjacent to the piston with a repeater. Since you are having the pistons go upward, it's easiest to power the block below them. The repeater is necessary to direct the power into the blocks when you have more than one piston side-by-side – otherwise, simple redstone wires will just form a line and direct the power past, not into, the block.

This video demonstrates the construction of an automatic-harvesting wheat farm, part of which is a piston design that does exactly what you're trying to do (the embed is set to skip to 7m25s where the piston wiring begins):